# adding Parallax Scrolling cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, parallax

currently I am adding my background via the method below. how can I modify the background so that it auto scrolls along with the tilemap.

```
- (void)setupParallax {

    NSString *backgroundName = [self.tilemap propertyNamed:@"BackgroundImage"];

    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[AssetHelper     
                       getDeviceSpecificFileNameFor:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"background-%@.png",backgroundName]]];
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    [self addChild:background z:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `CCParallaxNode`. Your background and map would be children of the parallaxNode, and when you move it, its children will automatically move accordingly. Assuming the background should be behind your map, the code will look something like this.-

```
CCParallaxNode *voidNode = [CCParallaxNode node];    
[voidNode addChild:background z:10 parallaxRatio:ccp(0.8f, 0.8f) positionOffset:ccp(0, 0)];
[voidNode addChild:map z:20 parallaxRatio:ccp(1.0f, 1.0f) positionOffset:ccp(0, 0)];
[self addChild:voidNode];
```

`ParallaxRatio` will set the speed of each layer based on `ParallaxNode` movement:

- `(1.0, 1.0)` means that the map will move at the same speed that the voidNode among x and y.
- `(0.8, 0.8)` means that the background will move 80% slower than the `ParallaxNode`

Comment: i'm receiving an error this line when adding the above code to the end of my existing code above `    [voidNode addChild:map z:20 parallaxRatio:ccp(1.0f, 1.0f) positionOffset:ccp(0, 0)];`

Comment: Which error? I'm guessing that `map` could be `nil` at the time of adding it to `voidNode`.